# Editing a .JET file in 7-ZIP is not saving to the archive

Tags: passwords, 7-zip

So, I'm trying to edit a `.jet` file as an archive.
And every time I edit the files inside it, like every time I back out of Notepad++ to edit something else, it does not prompt me to update the archive with the modification like it should.
Any idea how to fix this?

**Edit:**
Although I might have mentioned this, the `.jet` file requires a password to edit, if that might affect anything.